# Pixel Shader to OpenGL converter

Tags: graphics, 3d, animations, emulation, wii

I am running ubuntu 11.10 on my computer and I would like to emulate a wii. I have a wii emulator running successfully on ubuntu, but it requires pixel shader. I am most sure that my graphics card has OpenGL, but am also sure that it doesn't have pixel shader. It would be very helpful if there was a driver that tricked the emulator that i have pixel shader, when I am infact using OpenGL for the animation.

Comment: I think the emulator requires the pixel shader for a reason - i.e. it uses it to draw the image. "tricking" it into thinking the feature is supported while it's absent would produce... I don't know, something from visual artifacts to blank screen. (also, OpenGL support is a feature of the driver, while pixel shader is a hardware feature of the card, I'm not sure why you think having OpenGL renders pixel shader unnecessary)

Comment: Are you saying that OpenGL is just driver software? Does the software just use it's own drivers for pixel shader? I'm just wanting some drivers that translate the pixel shader signals into OpenGL signals.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, OpenGL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL is a software API which may use hardware capabilities of the card or software emulation to render 3D scenes.

Pixel shaders http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_shader are one of the card's hardware features and supported by OpenGL 2.0 and above.

Mesa3D http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesa_3D is an open-source implementation of OpenGL API which has software mode and fully supports OpenGL up to 3.0, so I suppose it should be able to render shaders in one form or another.

The catch, however, is that it's going to be painfully slow - there's a reason why they call video cards "3D accelerators"